# Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1j PHP/7.4.16 Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp

I am facing this issue when i was trying to open (localhost/wordpress)
this error is showing

Comment: What and where is the issue ?? Please read this carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add clear information for the user.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue while working on Magento 2.4.2. Following workaround worked for me.

Step 1: Set the root directory to 'magento2/pub'

- go to file C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
- Paste below code at the bottom of the file.

  <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento24/pub"
  ServerName yourname.magento.com

  Replace  with your project name.

Step 2: Update the local host domain

- goto file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
- Paste below code at the bottom of file.

  127.0.0.1  yourname.magento.com

Step 3: Update base URL in database.

- goto magento db and run the below sql query.
  UPDATE core_config_data SET value='http://yourname.magento.com/' WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url';

Step 4: Update env.php file

- goto file: app/etc/env.php
- Paste below code at the bottom of the file.

  'directories' => [
  'document_root_is_pub' => true
  ]

Step 5: Enable developer mode

- run below commands on cmd from your project directory.

  php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
  php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

You need to put wordpress in the correct folder so apache can read the php files and serve the content to clients connecting to the url. Moreover please consider using an FQDN resolver by your interlan dns server or forcing the resolution modifying the 'hosts' file.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you have created several files on different directories as it may cause this error

make sure it's only on the C:/xampp/htdocs/(create a new folder by the name login)/(save your file here)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).